# How to extract first file from cbz files in one batch?

Tags: command-line, files, archive, batch

I have a collection of comic books that I store on my computer, mostly in `.cbz` format (which is just a ZIP archive, but with a fancy name). Recently, I decided to make a collage of the covers of a specific comic series, for which I'd need the first file in the comic book archive.

Here's the breakdown of the problem:

- 75 `.cbz` files in a single folder;
- Each file has a name like `<series name> #<issue number>`, where issue numbers go from 1 to 75 (one problem: it's not like 01, 02, 03, etc, so there may be a confusion with sorting there);

  - Each file inside each archive is named like `<issue name> <3-digit issue number with preceding zeros>`
- Archives can be renamed to `.zip` if necessary, but I know 7Zip (and some other archivers, but not unrar) handles CBZ well enough;

What I need:

- The first file from each of the 75 archives. The files already have distinctive names, so there's no need to rename them at the output.

What I have:

- Ubuntu 16.04
- 7Zip
- Internet connection

How do I make this happen? What command will extract the first file from every archive in a folder to the same folder?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to rename output files then I suggest something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in *.cbz
do
 cover="`zipinfo -2 "$file" | awk 'NR==2 {exit} 1'`"
 unzip -j "$file" "$cover"
done;
```

Save it in a file like `script.sh` and put it into the same directory as your comics are. Then give it execute permission:

```
chmod +x script.sh
```

And run it:

```
./script.sh
```

---

#### How does it work?

We can get a list of all files within a zip archive using `zipinfo`:

```
zipinfo -2 mycomic.cbz
```

it outputs something similar to:

```
First file within the archive.jpg
Second file within the archive.jpg
...
```

Then using `awk 'NR==1 { print }'` we can return the first file name which is: `First file within the archive.jpg`.

Now to extract this file I can use a `unzip` like:

```
unzip -j mycomic.cbz "First file within the archive.jpg"
```

Comment: Got an error for each file without any output: `Archive:  Lucifer #10.cbz
caution: filename not matched:`

Comment: @Gallifreyan Updated, check it again ;)

Comment: It worked!... But extracted the 2nd page of every issue (i.e. the files end with `002`) :D

Comment: Change the `NR==2` to `NR==1` see if you get the desired result ;)

Comment: Yep, that worked perfectly! Now how does that magic work, really? Would it work if the files in the archives weren't enumerated?

Comment: We just get a list of all files within a `cbz` then we select the first one and extract it... simple!

Comment: Thanks for this, and thanks for the explanation! In case you wondered, [this is what I needed the script for](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0lZcsBY6MJoNnVOX21NYzJISFE) (60 Mb 5855x26998 JPG file!)

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad that it was helpful to you :-)

Comment: It might be more efficient to do something like `zipinfo -2 "$file" | awk 'NR==2 {exit} 1'` (doesn't require storing the whole zipinfo output to a variable, or processing the whole of it)

Comment: @steeldriver thanks, I read [this](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Exit-Statement.html), however I still can't get what that `1` does there.

Comment: @Ravexina ah sorry about that - `1` is a "golf" way of of writing a `{print}` action (by default, awk prints the current record if a rule evaluates to `true`)